# Prove a set is open for every r in R

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

$x\in X$

Show that $\{y \in X \mid d(y,x) > r\}$ is open for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$

---

First I define $\{y \in X \mid d(y,x) > r\}=M$

In order to prove that $M$ is open for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ I can prove that every $z\in\mathbb{R}$ is an interior point of M, as it would be open per definition.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: First figure out what $d(x,z)$ is.  i.e. let $m = d(x,z) > r$.  Now it's a matter of finding an $\epsilon$ in terms of $m$ and $r$ so that if $d(z,y) < \epsilon$ then $d(y,x) > r$  Can you do that?  Hint: use triangle inequality to not that $d(x,z) \le d(y,x) + d(y,z) \implies m \le d(y,x) + d(y,z) $.  And $d(y,z) < \epsilon$ so ... what value of epsilon always makes it work?

Comment: Are you leading me towards: $d(x,z)≤d(y,x)+d(y,z)<ϵ+r=d(z,x)$ ?
I'm not 100% certain what you exactly mean. I think I'm slowly getting it (through the other comments as well as yours) but I am far from certain.

Comment: The basic rule  for proving $A$= any set is open in a metric space is to let $\epsilon=$ minimum distance from $z$ (in $A$) to "the edge" of $A$. and show that $d(z,y) < \epsilon$ means $y$ is within $A$. So in this case we have $d(z,x) > r$ so the distance from $z$ to "the edge where distance are $r$.  is $\epsilon = d(z,x) - r$.  i.e. $d(x,z)$ is  "beyond" $r$ by $d(x,z) - r$. So set $\epsilon =d(x,z) -r$ and then everything within $\epsilon$ of $z$ will still be "beyond" $r$. $d(y,z)<\epsilon\implies d(x,y)\ge d(x,z)-d(y,z)<d(x,y)-\epsilon=d(x,y)-d(x,y)+r=r$. $y$ in set, $x$ interior. QED.

Comment: I'm not leading you to $d(x,z) < d(z,x)$ but instead leasing you to $d(y,z) < e = d(z,x) -r \implies( [d(x,z)+d(z,y)\ge d(x,y)]\implies d(x,z)\ge d(x,y)-d(z,y)>d(x,y)-\epsilon = r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon = d(x,z) - r > 0$.

Then if $d(z, y) < \epsilon$ then $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+ d(y,z) \implies d(x,y) \ge d(x,z) - d(y,z) > d(x,z) - \epsilon = d(x,z) - (d(x,z) - r) = r$.

So $z$ is an interior point of the set.

====

So how did I come up with that, other than by copying others who did it before me.

Okay, I copied others who did it before me but what I *should* have done was reason it out:

It'd help if I could draw a picture.  But imagine:

.........[x - r....... x ...... x+ r] ...... z .........

That is a picture of $z \in \{y| d(y,x) > r\}$.  Do you see it?  I hope so.

So I want to show it is an interior point.  So I want this picture;

.........[x -r ..... x ...... x+r] ......(z - $\epsilon$ .... z .... z + $\epsilon$)....

Which is a picture of $B_{\epsilon}(z) \subset \{y| d(x,y) > r\}$.

So what epsilon will make this true?  Any $d(x,z) - \epsilon \ge r$ or $\epsilon \le d(x,z) - r$ will do.

=== older stuff that is kind of confusing, and once I thought about it, *ISN"T* actually what I would do at all ======

We pick a $z$ so that $d(z,x) > r$.  Set $d(z,x) = m > r$.

We don't know what $y$ is but we know that $d(y, z) < \epsilon_z$ for some value of $\epsilon_z$ but we don't really know which value of $\epsilon_z$ will work.

We want to show that $d(y,z) < \epsilon \implies d(x,y) > r$.

How could we possibly show that?  What could we know about $d(x,y)$?

Well, by Triangle inequality we can know that

1) $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(y,z) = m + \epsilon_z$.  Well, we can't show what d(x,y) is greater than by showing what it is less than or equal to, so that is useless.

2) $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z) \implies d(x,y) \ge d(x,z) - d(y,z) = m - d(y,z) > m - \epsilon_z$.  If we know that $m - \epsilon_z \ge r$ then this is perfect for us.

$m - \epsilon \ge r \implies \epsilon_z \le m - r$ will do.  As $m > r$ we can set $\epsilon = m - r$ and we will be done.

3) $d(y,z) \le d(x,y) + d(x,z) \implies d(x,y)\ge d(y,z) - d(x,z)= d(y, z) - m$ which if $d(y,z) < \epsilon$ which is small, is the same as saying $d(x,y) \ge $ a negative number, which... is cute, but can you really breath through that thing (as the elephant said to the naked man).

So 2) tells us what to do:

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $y\in M$ then $\rho:=d(x,y)-r>0$.

Comment: So if we let $z \in M$ then $\rho=d(x,y)-r>0$. And we have $B(z,\rho)⊂M$.
Then I should use the triangle inequality to prove it for all points z? 
Could you expand on where you get $\rho=d(x,y)-r>0$ ?

Comment: @Sirmimer By definition of $M$, $d(x,y)>r$ for $y\in M$. -- You use the triangle inequality that $B(y,\rho)\subseteq M$.

Comment: Can you give me further hints on how to prove that $B(y,\rho)⊆M$ using the triangle inequality? Should i choose another element in $B(y,\rho)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Pick a point in $M$, consider its distance from $x$, place a ball with an appropriate radius around it and use the triangle inequality to prove that the ball is contained in $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $X\setminus M$ is closed.