# Show a set is open (using balls and triangle inequality)

Tags: real-analysis

[Question]

Let $x\in X$

Show $\{y \in X \mid d(y,x) > r\}$ is open for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$

[Solution]

Let M be defined as $M = \{y \in X \mid d(y,x) > r\}$. Let $z\in M $ and set $r_1=d(z,x)-r$.

To show M is open for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ I will show that $B_{r_1}(z) \subset M$.

If $p \not\subset M$ then using the triangle inequality we have
$$d(z,x)≤d(z,p)+d(p,x)<r_1+r=d(z,x)$$

Which is a contradiction. It proves that $B_{r_1}(z) \subset M$, meaning $z$ is an interior point in M and thous M is open for every $r \in\mathbb{R}$

---

Any feedback on whether I've made any mistakes or misunderstood something or should try to expand on something would be appreciated.

Edit: spotted a mistake made while writing it in

Comment: I don't understand why from your reasoning should follow that $B_{r_1}(z) \subset M$. To prove it I would suggest you to take a point $p \in B_{r_1}(z)$ and show that $d(p,x)>r$ using the fact that $d(p,x) \geq d(x,z) - d(p,z) \dots$

Comment: I noted a mistake I made in the triangle inequality. Does it make more sense for you now or am I still some off?

Comment: It's complement is closed so it must be open. Try this way.

Comment: There's another mistake: you say "if $p \not\in B_{r_1}(z)$" but you have to prove that "if $p \not\in M$" then you get a contradiction (that is exactly what you did). So you just have to change $B_{r_1}(z)$ with $M$ and everything it's ok. Also look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168952/prove-a-set-is-open-for-every-r-in-r?rq=1 for other answers.

Comment: I've actually written (on paper) down $p ∉ B_{r_1}(z)$. Thank you!

Comment: A couple small errors; as you have it now. $p\not\subset M$ should be $p\notin M$. $p$ is a point, not a set. And you have not said anywhere that $p \in B_{r_1}(z)$, though your calculation and conclusion hinge on this. Another suggestion I have is that there is no need to do this as a proof by contradiction. The forward proof is more direct and easily comprehended. (i.e., since $d(x,z) \le d(x,p) + d(p,z) < d(x,p) + d(x,z) - r$, then $r \le d(x,p)$, so $p \in M$).

Comment: Thanks for the correction.